# How to become a graphic designer?

Tags: software-recommendation, designers, resource-recommendations

Ever since I was a little girl I've discovered my passion for drawing. I didn't finished a college related to drawing or graphic design, and as a result I don't have an idea of what it means to be a graphic designer, but I would like to know.

In what categories is graphic design divided? What jobs can you have? What do you need to learn to become a graphic designer? What programs/software should I learn?

Please do not take this as a joke, I want to learn and start my career in this field and I don't know where to start.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Christina! Welcome to GD.SE. Most of your questions are already answered here, for example the different areas of graphic design, the jobs... I suggest you first take a look at our existing questions, and then edit yours to reflect particular doubts you might encounter. As it is, this questions is very broad. What is personally important for you? Are you consider other careers? The more specific the question, the better.

Comment: Not to be too snarky, but [have you done *any* research?](https://www.google.com/webhp?tab=iw&ei=Jn_nVOjEBMKggwT-noL4Cg&ved=0CAUQqS4oAg#safe=off&q=How+to+become+a+graphic+designer%3F)